# Magento from 1.3 to 1.4

Tags: php, magento, export, product, catalog

I`m using Magento 1.3 and I want to test the new 1.4, but is there a way of exporting the products and categories form 1.3 to 1.4?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up a new database, export your old database and import it into the new one, then install Magento with your new imported database's settings.  It will automatically upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to export products right through Magento, but there is no direct way to export categories.

To export products, login to the admin, and go to System >> Import/Export >> Profiles and then select the "Export All Products".  After you run that, the file will be in /var/export/

To import that into 1.4, go the same route but instead of selecting the "Export All Products" profile, select the "Import All Products".  Upload the file and run it.

Categories you'll have to get in the database and figure out everything you need to dump and move over.  It is definitely doable, I just don't know off the top of my head.  There's definitely more than one table you'll have to deal with.  They should start with "catalog_category_" in the database.

Answer (score 0):

I really needed to migrate from 1.3 to 1.4. I read every post on the internet about this and none of them worked. Some people claim that updating runs automatically, but you'll get only error after error. Please let me know if I'm mistaken and I would love to try it myself.
Having said that, you'll have to install Magento 1.4 from scratch. After that you can copy the media folder and then it's when the nightmare begins: migrating products.

You can export products from 1.3, but the CSV file is not compatible with 1.4.
I had to write a script for transforming 1.3 export files to 1.4 import files. Then I could import products to Magento 1.4. But images on the backend didn't work because they are retrieved from cache so I had to correct this. That wasn't easy.

Templates are more or less compatible, a few issues with pagination and other minor changes.

I'm not sure how to migrate users yet, but I'm using the same technique I used for products. Who know if passwords are easy to preserve, and forget about migrating orders, at least without investing some money on it.

Comment: I've done a few 1.3->1.5 migrations that were fussy, but the database changes handled my the model were never an issue for me. The accepted answer has actually worked flawlessly for me, except the changes to the template system which had to be worked out.

Comment: Basically, I tried installing 1.5 over an existing 1.3 database. I kept getting "Table or view already exists" error. I wonder how it is possible for the installation script to convert a database from version 1.3 to 1.5